# How can resolve an error of compilation in NS2

Tags: ns2

I installed ns-allinone-2.35 then I run  **ns aodv.tcl**  so it works  **BUT**  when I changed in  **aodv.cc**  (i just added a  **printf ("hello")**  in the forward () function), then I compiled using  **"make"**  so I got this error:

```
rm -f gen/version.c
/home/amira/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/tclsh8.5 bin/string2c.tcl version_string < VERSION > gen/version.c
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create gen/version.c: Permission denied
make: *** [gen/version.c] Error 2
```

How to resolve this please!

Answer (score 0):

If you unpacked ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz with sudo, or with a Windows© tool, then you will experience "Permission denied" : When running `$ make` in ns-2.35 .

Please unpack a new "ns-allinone-2.35" in a new directory :

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz   // 2014 .. 2017 update
```

→ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

---

ns2-INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing